# looping and condition on string in r

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column based condition below:

```
if the `str` column only contains `A` then insert `A`
if the `str` column only contains `B` then insert `B`
if the `str` column only contains `A` and `B` then insert `AB`
```

```
df<-read.table(text="
ID   str
1    A
1    A
1    AA
1    ABB
2    BA 
2    BB", header=T)
```

```
ID   str   simplify_str
1    A        A
1    A        A
1    AA       A
1    ABB      AB
2    BA       AB
2    BB       B
```

Comment: Is it specifically these cases you're looking at? Or do you just want to show the unique characters that show up and have them be sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as `tidyverse` options are concerned, you could use `dplyr::case_when` with `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(simplify_str = case_when(
        str_detect(str, "^A+$") ~ "A",
        str_detect(str, "^B+$") ~ "B",
        TRUE ~ "AB"))
#  ID str simplify_str
#1  1   A            A
#2  1   A            A
#3  1  AA            A
#4  1 ABB           AB
#5  2  BA           AB
#6  2  BB            B
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your data.frame:

```
As <- grep("A",df$str)
Bs <- grep("B",df$str)
df$simplify_str <- ""
df$simplify_str[As] <- paste0(df$simplify_str[As],"A")
df$simplify_str[Bs] <- paste0(df$simplify_str[Bs],"B")
```

```
df
  ID str simplify_str
1  1   A            A
2  1   A            A
3  1  AA            A
4  1 ABB           AB
5  2  BA           AB
6  2  BB            B
```

Answer (score 2):

A general solution in base R where it splits the string and pastes together the `unique` characters in a sorted way.

```
df$simplify_str <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$str), ""), 
                   function(x) paste(unique(sort(x)), collapse = ""))

df
#  ID str simplify_str
#1  1   A            A
#2  1   A            A
#3  1  AA            A
#4  1 ABB           AB
#5  2  BA           AB
#6  2  BB            B
```